# Do-Release-Upgrade returns "no new release found"

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, server, upgrade

I'm currently running a 14.04 LTS Ubuntu server and I would like to upgrade it to 16.04. I have installed the `update-manager-core` tool and set it to search for LTS versions, but it returns "No new release found" every time.

```
daniel@Owncloud:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d -s
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

daniel@Owncloud:~$ cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=lts
```

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt-get update` before doing upgrade ?

Comment: Yep multiple times

Comment: Please restart your system and try again.

Comment: I have done that about 4 times without success

Comment: do `upgrade and dist-upgrade`.

Comment: I have also done that

Comment: So sry! I got disconnected but I'm back. But i did try the upgrade without -d flag without any luck (Back in irc as well)

Comment: I am encountering exactly the same problem.

Comment: I turned out it was my IDS/IPS there was causing the error and not the operating system itself.

Comment: Same here, from 18:04 upwards.